# Botframework V4 Error resolving type specified in JSON on FB Messenger

Tags: c#, json, botframework

My bot works well locally and in the web chat but returns an exception when I text it on Messenger.

```
Sorry, it looks like something went wrong. 
Error resolving type specified in JSON 'Bot.ConversationFlow, Bot'. 
Path 'ConversationFlow.$type'.
```

This class no longer exists. Any idea what it happens guys?

Thanks

Comment: Which class no longer exists? Can you debug it using Ngrok? https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/  Are there any other channels that you have connected it to that fail/succeed?

Comment: I deleted ConversationFlow as I started using dialogs. It works well in the web chat. I am going to try to debug later, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Solved: CosmosDB stored documents that stored a class that no longer exists. Clearing the database solved the issue.